# How to use ng-if or ng-show to make md-select removed(hide)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make a md-select removed or hide when a checkbox is not checked. 
I have tired both ng-if or ng-show, but once the md-select is displayed, it cannot be removed or hide. My code is as follows:

Using ng-if:

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="checked" ng-true-value="'true'" ng-false-value="'false'">
Add Dependency
</md-checkbox>

<p>Checkbox value: {{ checked }}</p>
<md-select  placeholder="Dependency" ng-model="test" style="min-width: 300px;" ng-if ="checked">
<md-option>testOption1</md-option>
<md-option>testOption2</md-option>
<md-option>testOption3</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Using ng-show

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="checked" ng-true-value="'true'" ng-false-value="'false'">
Add Dependency
</md-checkbox>

<p>Checkbox value: {{ checked }}</p>
<md-select  placeholder="Dependency" ng-model="test" style="min-width: 300px;" ng-show ="checked">
<md-option>testOption1</md-option>
<md-option>testOption2</md-option>
<md-option>testOption3</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Where did I do wrong? Thank you.

Comment: can you please fiddle it out the same?

Comment: It's because 'checked' is a String value and not a boolean. So, once it is checked, it will have a string value which is always evaluated to be true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have "ng-true-value" and "ng-false-value" as true/false strings not bools.  You can fix this by either...

Change ng-true-value="'true'" to ng-true-value="true"

```js
angular.module('sandbox', ['ngMaterial']);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div ng-app="sandbox">
  <md-checkbox ng-model="checked" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false">
  Add Dependency
  </md-checkbox>

  <p>Checkbox value: {{ checked }}</p>
  <md-select  placeholder="Dependency" ng-model="test" style="min-width: 300px;" ng-show ="checked">
  <md-option>testOption1</md-option>
  <md-option>testOption2</md-option>
  <md-option>testOption3</md-option>
  </md-select>
</div>
```

OR

Change ng-show="checked" to ng-show="checked === 'true'"

```js
angular.module('sandbox', ['ngMaterial']);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div ng-app="sandbox">
  <md-checkbox ng-model="checked" ng-true-value="'true'" ng-false-value="'false'">
  Add Dependency
  </md-checkbox>

  <p>Checkbox value: {{ checked }}</p>
  <md-select  placeholder="Dependency" ng-model="test" style="min-width: 300px;" ng-show ="checked === 'true'">
  <md-option>testOption1</md-option>
  <md-option>testOption2</md-option>
  <md-option>testOption3</md-option>
  </md-select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing to md-checkbox a true and false value which are 'true' (string) and 'false' (string). So when you write ng-if="checked" or ng-show="checked", angular is just checking your "checked" string variable is not undefined.

Try to remove this :

`ng-true-value="'true'" ng-false-value="'false'"`

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple, `ng-model` is enough to handle this. No need of `ng-true-value\ng-false-value`,  It's generally required when you need custom flag like `Yes\No`

So : `<md-checkbox ng-model="checked">` will do it for you.

See this [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nz9h6aje/)